# Software Center not opening in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, python

I'm a Linux Mint 14 user. I'm not able to open the software center.

```
$ software-center
ERROR:root:DebFileApplication import Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/init.py",
line 4, in from debfile import DebFileApplication, DebFileOpenError File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py",
line 25, in from softwarecenter.db.application import Application, AppDetails File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py",
line 27, in import softwarecenter.distro File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/init.py",
line 197, in distro_instance = _get_distro() File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/init.py",
line 172, in _get_distro module = import(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], -1) ImportError: No module named linuxmint Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/software-center",
line 128, in from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import SoftwareCenterAppGtk3 File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py",
line 53, in from softwarecenter.db.application import Application File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py",
line 27, in import softwarecenter.distro File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/init.py",
line 197, in distro_instance = _get_distro() File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/init.py",
line 172, in _get_distro module = import(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], -1) ImportError: No module named linuxmint
```

Comment: You really need to reformat the output, at least adding line separators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Tried to edit your question by placing the command output in a code block
but the [Community bot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) didn't like it.)*

Mint uses `mintInstall` as [Software Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint#Software_developed_by_Linux_Mint).

Using the Ubuntu `software-center` seems both hackish and prone for
unknown repercussions. I'm perhaps missing something here.

A better option is probably to use `synaptic`.

---

Anyhow; one way could be:

*(Tested on VirtualBox install of LinuxMint 14 KDE.)*
*(Note: I have no idea if this could mess up anything, if version detection is correct etc.)*

1. Purge current install: `sudo apt-get purge software-center`
2. Fake Ubuntu: `sudo vi`[/etc/lsb-release](http://community.linuxmint.com/iso/reports/12/44)

   ```
   Change:
   DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
   to
   DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
   ```
3. Reinstall software-center: `sudo apt-get install software-center`
4. When done change `DISTRIB_ID` back to `LinuxMint`.
5. Open: `sudo vi /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py`
6. `:set number<enter>` if you do not have numbers.
7. Go to line 166.
8. Change:

   ```
     distro_id = distro_info[0]
     to
     distro_id = "Ubuntu"
   ```

   It is part of `def get_distro()`

*(If you do not know vim use something else - or do this:)*

---

1. Go to line `:166<enter>`
2. <kbd>A</kbd> to enter insert mode. *(Append at end of line.)*
3. Change line. If you want add `# distro_info[0]` on next line or something to have it there for reference.
4. Exit insert mode by <kbd>ESC</kbd>.
5. Write file by `:w<enter>`
6. Quit by `:q<enter>` *(Or do 5 and 6 at once by `:wq<enter>`)*

---

That should be it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I wanted to write the exceptions in the comment but it was too long.
Can u please tell me what to do if I want  mintInstall back ?

Comment: It's showing exceptions like "dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/share/oneconf/oneconf-service exited with status 1"

Comment: @TusharMakkar Try: `sudo update-apt-xapian-index`